# how to package UWP app contains third-party dlls to appxbundle?

Tags: windows, dll, uwp

In my project, I have a windows runtime component which implemented in C++ and uses several third-party dlls. In my UWP project, I use this windows runtime component to do some calculations. I developed the UWP app in VS2015, and it runs correctly when I copied the related dlls to the workdir. But when I package this app, the genarated appxbundle can be installed correctly, but it crashed when excute calculation concern to the dlls, so I doubt such a crash is caused by the lack of dlls. Does any one have any idea about how to package dlls into appxbundle?

Answer (score 0):

The following link gives the correct answer. Just place dlls in the folder which the Pacakge.appxmanifest lies in. Then add the dlls to the projects and change the property "copy to output folder" to "always copy".

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/26013e5e-3ff1-44a0-8797-0474dabd12d0/uwpincluding-dlls-in-a-uwp-application-in-visual-studio?forum=wpdevelop